# Use default tab stop in a table of content in MS Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I'm using MS Word 2016 on Windows 10.

I've created a table of content with a TOC field code, and with default tab stops to 20 mm before the text (and after the numbering) for the level 2 of the TOC.
I have many tables of content in my file with the following kind of code: { TOC \f x \h \z }, which I want to keep since I find it practical.

However, when I'm updating the TOC, no text is moving to the default tab stop I've set (20 mm from the left).

I would like to set the tab stop only for the TOC 2 style (level 2 of the TOC, i.e. 2.1. and 2.2.) and automatically move the text to that tab stop, or after refreshing the TOC.
And I would like to let the TOC 1 as is, without custom tab stop.

How can I do that?

I've this:
[image]

I would like that tab between the number and the text, by default or at least when I'm updating the TOC:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/use-default-tab-stop-in-a-table-of-content/eb8518e0-10f4-4271-b61a-411ee136b3b0 ----
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: A Message to Forum Cross-Posters https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 0):

### With an out-of-the box setup, change the tab stop in one of your level 2 entries to be what you want.

The TOC styles should be set to automatically update the style when you make changes.

If this does not happen, find the TOC 2 style and right-click on it to update to match formatting.

Here are two references that may assist you:

- [TOC Tips and Tricks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm) by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill
- [How to Create a Table of Contents](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/tableofcontents.html) by Word MVP Shauna Kelly